# MongoDB - Remove null values in objects inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a sample document with an array of objects

```
[
  { 
    array_a: [{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": null}, ...],
    array_b: [{"key4": "val1", "key5": null, "key6": null}, ...]
  }, 
  ... 
]
```

How can I remove the keys with the value `null`? To become:

```
[
  { 
    array_a: [{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}, ...],
    array_b: [{"key4": "val1"}, ...]
  }, 
  ... 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit long query.

1. `$set`

   1.1. (`array_a`) `$map` - Iterate array from *1.1.1* and return new array.

   1.1.1. `input` - `$map` - Convert each document in `array_a` to key-value pair array: `[{ k: "key1", v: "val1" }]`.

   1.1.2. `$filter` - Filter the document (key-value pair) with `v` is not `null`.

   1.2. (`array_b`) Same explanation with *1.1*.
2. `$set`

   2.1. (`array_a`) `$filter`

   2.1.1 `input` - `$map` - Iterate each array document in the array to return an array with object.

   2.1.2 `cond` - Filter the document which is not empty document `{}`.

   2.2. (`array_b`) - Same explanation with *2.1*.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "array_a": {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$array_a",
              in: {
                $objectToArray: "$$this"
              }
            }
          },
          in: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$$this",
              as: "kv",
              cond: {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    "$getField": {
                      "field": "v",
                      "input": "$$kv"
                    }
                  },
                  null
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "array_b": {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$array_b",
              in: {
                $objectToArray: "$$this"
              }
            }
          },
          in: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$$this",
              as: "kv",
              cond: {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    "$getField": {
                      "field": "v",
                      "input": "$$kv"
                    }
                  },
                  null
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "array_a": {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$array_a",
              in: {
                $arrayToObject: "$$this"
              }
            }
          },
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$this",
              {}
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "array_b": {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$array_b",
              in: {
                $arrayToObject: "$$this"
              }
            }
          },
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$this",
              {}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U1900VC5D9S)

*Note: The `$set` stages can combine into one, separate into multiple stages for better readable.*

Comment: Thanks and my bad. I made the edit to original post. The solution here is almost perfect. If I edit the documents in mongo playground, I still have issue. Rather than removing the entire object, I'd like to remove just the field that is null.  Here is the updated one: https://mongoplayground.net/p/w5pSZ4ukS-m

Comment: Thinking you can refer to this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U1900VC5D9S). I will update the answer once back.